# Spring Data + Solr 6.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, solr

I've a strange behaviour with Spring-Data + Solr6.x.

1) Bean declaration

```
@Id
@Indexed(name=EventSchema.id) //I also try without this annotation
private String id;
```

2) Repo

```
solrTemplate.saveBean(event);
solrTemplate.commit();
```

3) Error

```
org.springframework.data.solr.UncategorizedSolrException: Error from server at http://192.168.99.100:8983/solr/eventCore: Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id; nested exception is org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://192.168.99.100:8983/solr/eventCore: Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id
at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.execute(SolrTemplate.java:172) ~[spring-data-solr-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.saveBean(SolrTemplate.java:219) ~[spring-data-solr-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.saveBean(SolrTemplate.java:213) ~[spring-data-solr-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

This exception appears after a migration from solr 5.x to 6.2 (same sw code).

How can I force, in solr 6.2 (or spring?), to auto-generate ID if document.id is null?

Answer (score 0):

To generate the id automatically you could add this in your solrconfig file

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain>
 <processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory">
  <str name="fieldName">id</str>
 </processor>
 <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
 <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

And must also add id field & uniqueKey in your schema.

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```